# Is there a container type which saves by value and not by reference, unlike list?

Tags: python

I wonder if there is a list type, which saves by value and not by reference.

I think the use cases are pretty obvious.

The only workaround that I can think of right now is using a deep copy, for every element I add to the list, which is pretty inefficient and requires more coding than it should.

What I want is an in-built type, which saves by value.

Comment: What is the obvious use case ?

Comment: You could write a container type that copies elements as you add them, as long as you know what type of the elements is and can specify to copy them. There is no universal way to copy an object.

Comment: The short answer is no, because that's just not how Python works. Everything is an object, and we pass around references to those objects.

Comment: Mutable types copy by reference - it`s one of python basic rules and you need to break it explicitly, no built-in container will make hidden deepcopy for ypu

Comment: @Trizalio mutable and immutable objects are treated exactly the same, but with immutable ones it's less relevant whether or not they're handled by reference or value!

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a in-built list, I think the answer should be **no** due to [Python's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L9-L26) of list. As shown in the source code, Python list is defined as a C struct with an array of pointers `**ob_item` pointing to the address of elements of the list. Therefore, `List` type in Python can only store values by reference.

Comment: Ok, I guess doing a deep copy will have to do then.